# TypeScript: Reinitializing static data in a subclass? (or other mechanism to store gobal data)

Tags: typescript, static, extends, overriding

I have some static data which I want to access through some API with basic logic. (Namely, it's metadata about Java classes.)

I've put the API to few static methods of a class, and the data stub to a static field.

Then, in a subclass (which is generated), I redefine the field with some array. And I could access the same field from both parent and subclass. Not sure. I suspect this used to work but stopped working as TS 2.0 got stricter.

Anyway. I am looking for a mechanism to implement this properly. I need to access it all statically, those are data used globally. In Java, I'd probably make the parent a singleton and manipulated the static data trough there in `static {}` (however horrible that may sound).

What would be the equivalent in TypeScript?

```
class A {
    static foo = [-1];
    static getLastFoo(){ return A.foo[A.foo.length-1]; } 
}

class B extends A {
    static foo = [1,2,3]; // Did this work in TS 1.8?
}

B.getLastFoo(); // <--- gives 3
```

I assume this is somehow possible through the prototypes. Not sure if TypeScript allows that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should not work in typescript 1.8 as well, as you're doing:

```
return A.foo[A.foo.length - 1];
```

Which should always return `-1`, if you want it to return `3` then it should be doing:

```
class A {
    static foo = [-1];
    static getLastFoo() { return this.foo[this.foo.length - 1]; }
}
```

`this` in the static context is the class and not instance, so when invoking the `getLastFoo` function on `B` it will use `B.foo`.

---

#### Edit

This:

```
class A {
    static x = 3;
    static fn() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

Compiles into this:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    A.fn = function () {
        console.log(this);
    };
    A.x = 3;
    return A;
}());
```

It's clear here that `this` inside `A.fn` is `A`, and that `this.x` is the `A.x`.

Comment: Great. I figured out that actually I used to have this., but it was then changed by other team member and the static field made `private` :)   Is the `this` for static context documented somewhere thoroughly? Some language specification part?

Comment: I'm unaware of any documentation on this subject, but if you look at the compiled code you can see why `this` in static functions is the class. Check my revised answer.